# Add space reg ex in xsd

Tags: xml, regex, xsd

I have an xml file with the following line to it.

```
<asin ISBN="1234567890 1234567890123" code="aB1234Av">
```

i want to write a restriction on the ISBN with the given format. By that i mean 10 digit first then a space and then 13 digit.  I tried a regex but its not working. Here's my xsd.

```
<xsd:schema  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xsd:element name="asin">

        <xsd:attribute name="ISBN">

            <xsd:simpleType>

                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">

                    <xsd:pattern value="[0-9]{10}[^ ][0-9]{13}"/>

                </xsd:restriction>

            </xsd:simpleType>

        </xsd:attribute>

    </xsd:element>

</xsd:schema>
```

Can someone help me solve this please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`[^ ]`](http://regex101.com/r/xX0kT6) is a [*negated* character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) that says anything ***but*** a space, try it with `[ ]`, , or `\s`.

```
<xsd:pattern value="[0-9]{10}[ ][0-9]{13}"/>
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/hC3tD9)

Comment: or like this `\d{10} \d{13}`

Comment: Yup, I tried to keep it as similar to OP as possible but that works too :)

Comment: \d does not mean the same as [0-9]. The former allows non-Western digits, e.g. Thai or Indic digits.

Comment: In most cases though, it is still beneficial and tends to read easier for someone familiar with expressions.